# How to pass object in code and bind to it in XAML page?

Tags: xamarin, binding

I get the object when the item is tapped in a Listview.

```
async private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var vm = BindingContext as MeetingViewModel;
            var meeting = e.Item as MeetingPOCO;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Attendees_Page(meeting));
        }
```

In the next new page I create the object

```
public partial class Attendees_Page : ContentPage
    {
        private MeetingPOCO thisMeeting;
        public MeetingPOCO ThisMeeting
        {
            get { return thisMeeting; }
            set
            {
                thisMeeting = value;
            }
        }
        public Attendees_Page(MeetingPOCO meeting)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ThisMeeting = meeting;
        }
```

In XAML, I bind to the object:

```
<ListView x:Name="MeetingLV"
            Margin="05,0,0,0" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding ThisMeeting}"    
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            SeparatorVisibility="None"
            >
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                               
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding MeetingDate, StringFormat='{0:MM/ dd/ yyyy}'}"
                                       Style="{StaticResource MyLabels}"
                                   Grid.Column="0"/>
```

The result is a blank page. How do I pass the "meeting" object and bind to it in another page?

Comment: you need to set the `BindingContext` for the page

Comment: and, if `ThisMeeting` is not an `IEnumerable` you can't use it as a `ListView` `ItemSource`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First，you can't bind a model to ListView's ItemSource:

> A ListView is populated with data using the ItemsSource property,
> which can accept any collection implementing **IEnumerable**.

I wrote a simple example to show how to set the `ItemsSource` :

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //ThisMeeting = meeting;

        ThisMeeting = new MeetingPOCO() { MeetingDate = "123"};

        ObservableCollection<MeetingPOCO> dataSource = new ObservableCollection<MeetingPOCO>();

        dataSource.Add(ThisMeeting);

        MeetingLV.ItemsSource = dataSource;
    }

    private MeetingPOCO thisMeeting;
    public MeetingPOCO ThisMeeting
    {
        get { return thisMeeting; }
        set
        {
            thisMeeting = value;
        }
    }
}

public class MeetingPOCO
{
    public string MeetingDate { get; set; }
}
```

And of you want to use binding, it should be something like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //ThisMeeting = meeting;

        ThisMeeting = new MeetingPOCO() { MeetingDate = "123"};

        MeetingPOCO pocp = new MeetingPOCO();
        pocp.dataSource.Add(ThisMeeting);
        BindingContext = pocp;
    }

    public MeetingPOCO ThisMeeting { get; set; }
}

public class MeetingPOCO
{
    public ObservableCollection<MeetingPOCO> dataSource { get;set;}

    public string MeetingDate { get; set; }

    public MeetingPOCO()
    {
        dataSource = new ObservableCollection<MeetingPOCO>();
    }
}
```

And in Xaml, bind to `dataSource`:

```
<ListView x:Name="MeetingLV"
        Margin="05,0,0,0" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding dataSource}"    
        HasUnevenRows="True"
        SeparatorVisibility="None"
        >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding MeetingDate}"/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

You can read the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding#data-binding) and find examples there about how to binding.